# Iterating DSS response in BPEL (WSO2 BPS)

Tags: bpel, wso2, apache-synapse

I am using `WSO2 BPS and WSO2 DSS`.
DSS has `2 services` as below:
(1) Returns list of status and
(2) Inserts a record into table.

I succeeded invoking both the DSS services from `BPEL Workflow`. But I need to achieve the following thing.
My 1st DSS will return "List of Status". I have to iterate(using `'forEach' or 'while'` or ...) that response and pick particular node(`StatusDescription`) from it and use it for the next DSS call. My 1st DSS response is below.

```
<Response xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <Status>
        <StatusId>1</StatusId>
        <StatusDescription>Active</StatusDescription>
    </Status>
    <Status>
        <StatusId>2</StatusId>
        <StatusDescription>Inactive</StatusDescription>
    </Status>
</Response>
```

Can anyone suggest some tutorial or code snippet that would iterate through above DSS response?  i.e, My `bpel:finalCounterValue` will be '2' as there are 2 'Status' nodes in the above XML.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There is no reason to iterate using BPEL activities. Just use an ordinary XPath expression in an assignment. Something like `<from>$VariableName/*[child::StatusId = 2]/StatusDescription</from>` (omitting namespaces) should do the trick.

Comment: You are right joergl. But the above response is only a sample. In real, the number of status may differ(dynamic). So, I have to look into some other option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found the the way to iterate the nodes. Please find the code snippet below.

```
<bpel:forEach parallel="no" counterName="Counter" name="ForEach">
            <bpel:startCounterValue>
                <![CDATA[1]]>
            </bpel:startCounterValue>
            <bpel:finalCounterValue>                
                <![CDATA[count($GetStatusPLResponse.parameters/ns:Status)]]>
            </bpel:finalCounterValue>
            <bpel:scope>
                <!-- Some activity goes here. Say Assign or Invoke or .... -->
            </bpel:scope>
        </bpel:forEach>
```

The `count` method available under the namespace `xmlns:bpel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"` helps us to find count of nodes(`'Status'`).
The `count` method returns the value '2' and so `'forEach'` iterates twice.

Have Happy Learning.